# set dynamic base url on on live in Codeignito

Tags: php, codeigniter

set dynamic base url on on live in ci

$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/demo';

when i upload it on live and when live url changes the url is automatically  need to change on live ,help me

Comment: I didn't have problems so far leaving base_url empty in config... Try it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use it like this -
In localhost :
$config['base_url'] = "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/foldername/";

Just be sure in live if you are using subdomain then it would be like this - 
$config['base_url'] = "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/subdomainfolder/";

if your files are in root then it should be :
$config['base_url'] = "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/";

Please check it and revert if not solved.